# Date format in calendar panel popout

Tags: gnome, 20.04, calendar

[image]

Is there any way to change the date format in the calendar header or get it to respect the current locale? Also the day abbreviations are still in English even though the locale is set to Icelandic. The day abbreviations are OK in the full calendar app.

This is my `~/.pam_environment` file

```
LANGUAGE    DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LANG    DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC  DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_TIME DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_PAPER    DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_NAME DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS  DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE    DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT  DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION   DEFAULT=is_IS.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE   DEFAULT=a4
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that one must install a couple of language support package.

```
sudo apt install language-pack-is firefox-locale-is
```

*If I recall correctly this happened automatically in older versions of Ubuntu when going to settings and language options.*